# Prolog - Updating Dynamic Lists

Tags: list, search, dynamic, prolog

I want to update two dynamic lists for a breadth search. Although they do update in the background, their value that got instantiate in the initiate predicate wont update.

```
initialise(Start) :-
    retractall(openlist(_)),
    retractall(closedlist(_)),
    assert(openlist([(Start,Start)])),
    assert(closedlist([])).
```

Here the open list and the closed on are respectively, initiated to [(Start,Start)] and []

i then iterate my search but the OPEN and CLOSE Variables wont update, although the openlist and closedlist do update (if i run listing(openlist) or listing(closedlist) they do update but only once  and only for the first iteration. After that they are locked into those variables)

```
iterate :-
    openlist(OPEN),
    closedlist(CLOSE),
    OPEN = [(X,Y)|T],
    append(CLOSE,OPEN,R1),
    retractall(openlist(_)),
    retractall(closedlist(_)),
    assert(closedlist(R1)),
    back(X,M),
    append(M,OPEN,Result),
    diff(Result, R1, M3),
    assert(openlist(M3)).
```

any idea as to why this is happening?

thanks !

Comment: In Prolog, assert/retract **must not** be (ab)used. Make your procedure recursive, and 'update' your variables as a collateral effect of recursive calls.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Because this is for a breadth search and i m assigning a starting node to the open list. i have a third predicate that will trigger this iteration thus updating both lists. Passing the searched node tot he closed list and adding the new discovered ones to the openlist.

Comment: Using assert and retract like you are doing is errorprone and slow. It is also so different from how Prolog is normally written that people would have trouble figuring out what your code is doing (and you seem to be having trouble, too).

Comment: But then how should i append new lists to the ones in my dynamic lists?

Comment: What is a "dynamic list"? Do you have a link where this term is used? Maybe it will make more sense if I see it explained.

Comment: Basicly at the start of my programm, i created two list with the help of this syntax : `:- dynamic openlist/1, closedlist/1.`. They enable me to store a list in them and can't be "accessed/updated" without assert or retract. [link](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=declare) See the dynamic section below

Comment: Those are not lists, those are predicates. Either way, a precursory google search for "prolog breadth first search" returned some decently good implementations. This looks maybe most thorough: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/771/current/presentations/prolog%20search.pdf. There is also a whole chapter on searches in "The Craft of Prolog".